# Passar valores para uma struct

Tags: c, struct

Boa tarde.

Estou em duvida se é possível passar valores para uma struct em C usando JSON, hibernate ou algum outro método conhecido?

Comment: O reaf/write de apontadores (como char*) é algo tipicamente não textual. e estás a escrever um endereço de memória... A escrita e leitura de apontadores, só poderia funcionar dentro do mesmo processo (dentro da mesma sessão)

Comment: Qual a finalidade? Sem isso a resposta será demasiado ampla.

Comment: quero passar os valores que recolho do banco de dados para uma struct em C

Comment: Então, para constar - isso se chama "serialização" (no caso, para ler de volta, "desserialização")

Comment: Você percebeu que não há uma forma "automatica" de fazer isso - você teve que criar um mini-protocolo para a serialização - no seu caso,marcar os campos de string e inteiro  com um caractér especial. Há milhares de difrentes protocolos de serialização no mundo - e depende da aplicação, pode valer a pena adotar um mais padronizado, a fim de que outros programas possam entender seus dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ai galera, consegui resolver o problema, vou deixar o código para caso alguém precise qualquer dia desses**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)){
    char *s;
    int *x;
}my_struct;

void *chr2struct(const char *text){
    char c;
    my_struct *mst = (my_struct *) malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
    void **swap = (void **) malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
    void **res = swap;

    if(!text)
        return 0;

    int i;
    while(*text){
        c = *text;
        text++;
        char str[32];
        int x, len;
        char *data;
        switch(c){
            case 's':
            case 'c':
                sscanf(text,"%[^\037]",str);
                text += strlen(str)+1;
                len = atoi(str);
                data = (void *) malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
                strcpy(data,text);
                text+= len+1;
                swap[i] = data;
                break;
            case 'i':
                sscanf(text,"%[^\037]",str);
                text += strlen(str)+1;
                len = atoi(str);
                data = (void *) malloc(sizeof(int)*len);
                for(x=0; x<len; x++){
                    sscanf(text,"%i",&data[x]);
                    sprintf(str,"%i",data[x]);
                    text+=strlen(str)+1;
                    swap[i] = *data;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    my_struct *mst;
    mst = (my_struct *) chr2struct("s16\037qwertyuiopasdfgh\0i1\03716\0");
    printf("%s | %i\n", mst->s, mst->x);
}
```

Comment: Se estás a aprender C, aconselho-te a usar um compilador de C em vez dum compilador de C++. Aprender C usando um compilador de C++ é como aprender sueco com um professor dinarmaquês.

Comment: **Liga todos os warnings do teu compilador e toma atenção aos avisos!**

Comment: Eu programo direto pelo terminal do linux, não uso ide, quanto ao compilador uso o gcc mesmo, e os warnings, só teve um no sscanf que le um inteiro, mas no momento não pretendo criar uma variável inteira para receber os valores em inteiro.

Comment: Hmmm, nao reparei no `<malloc.h>`. De qualquer maneira deves preferir o `<stdlib.h>` (que reparei que nao existe no codigo) e deixar de fazer a conversao ao valor devolvido pelo `malloc()`.